# Sw Tool Linking to open source libraries

Tags: licensing, software, open-source-software

If I link proprietary code with open source libraries (licensed under the Apache v2 and MPL1.1 licenses) to create a standalone SW Tool, do I need to release the proprietary code under open source license terms?

I think the only license that requires this is GPL - which is very "reciprocal", so I don't think I'm required to do that for the above licenses.
However, MPL1.1 and Apache 2 are not compatible.

Since these two libraries do not get intermixed and are used in binary upon "call" from proprietary code can I distribute the SW Tool including both licenses in the respective sw packages?

Answer (score 0):

License compatibility generally only affects when you take projects, and relicense them under a different set of terms.

In your case, the Apache 2.0 license cannot be relicensed under the Mozilla Public License 1.1. However, *you're not relicensing under Mozilla.* Needless to say, you're not relicensing anything under an open source license. It's proprietary.

So what do you need to do? Nothing. Just follow and respect the license terms.

Comment: zizouz, please answer the question and don't worry about the votes. c'mon...

Comment: Since these two oss libraries do not get intermixed and are used in binary upon "call" from prop. code can i distribute the SW Tool including both oss licenses in the respective sw packages?

Comment: those oss libraries will abviously need to be distributed with the tool, otherwise it won't work. because of this i need to share the licenses as well, my question was where?

Comment: @paulblack I highly urge you to read the licenses yourself so that you can get a better understanding of them. The Apache license is permissive, so it's not one that you completely need to worry about, but the MPL runs on a file-wide copyleft system. Did you change the files? You need to release those files if you did. I don't necessarily want to interpret entire licenses for you - you should get a lawyer for that. I'm in high school.

Comment: my question is very simple. probably the answer to it is also simple - although i don't have the answer. no code was changed. but the oss libraries will be part of the tool and distributed together. So at the end of the day i'm distributing the oss libraries. These 2 do not get mixed so - i think - i do not need to worry about the incompatibilty issue. But i do need to provide a copy of the licenses - again: can i distribute the SW Tool including both oss licenses in the respective sw packages?

Comment: and if you're in high school - sorry I should be more patient then... but why would you like to answer questions that involve Canadian law, criminal law, and various copyright and licensing questions??